# memcpy prepending instead mem write?

Tags: c, memcpy

````
char str[50];
char strToCopy[16];
int numberOfBytesToFill = 7; // fills 1st n bytes of the memory area pointed to
char charToFillInAs = '*'; //48: ascii for '0' // '$';
void* targetStartAddress = str;
strncpy(strToCopy, "tO sEe The wOrLd", strlen("tO sEe The wOrLd")+1);
puts(strToCopy); // print

strcpy(str, "Test statement !@#$%^&*()=+_~```::||{}[]");
puts(str); // print

memset(targetStartAddress, charToFillInAs, numberOfBytesToFill); // fill memory with a constant byte (ie. charToFillInAs)
puts(str); // print

memcpy(targetStartAddress, strToCopy, strlen(strToCopy)+1); // +1 for null char   
puts(str); // print
````

The output is:

````
tO sEe The wOrLd
Test statement !@#$%^&*()=+_~```::||{}[]
*******atement !@#$%^&*()=+_~```::||{}[]
tO sEe The wOrLd*******atement !@#$%^&*()=+_~```::||{}[]
````

Hence, my question is why

````
tO sEe The wOrLd*******atement !@#$%^&*()=+_~```::||{}[]
````

instead of

````
tO sEe The wOrLd\0#$%^&*()=+_~```::||{}[]
````

with `'\0'` as the null char?

Comment: Because your string is 17 characters long and your buffer is only 16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
strncpy(strToCopy, "tO sEe The wOrLd", strlen("tO sEe The wOrLd")+1);
```

This is the wrong way to use `strncpy`. You should specify the size of the output buffer, not the size of the input. In this case the output buffer is 16 bytes, but you are copying 17 bytes into it, which results in undefined behavior.

Note that even if you do specify the output buffer size, `strncpy` won't write the null terminator if the string is truncated so you'd need to add it yourself:

```
strncpy(strToCopy, "tO sEe The wOrLd", sizeof(strToCopy));
strToCopy[sizeof(strToCopy)-1] = '\0';  //null terminate in case of truncation.
```

For this reason, some people prefer to use another function. For example, you can implement a safe copy function by using `strncat`:

```
void safeCopy(char *dest, const char *src, size_t destSize) {
    if (destSize > 0) {
        dest[0] = '\0';
        strncat(dest, src, destSize-1);
    }
}
```

To be used like:

```
safeCopy(strToCopy, "tO sEe The wOrLd", sizeof(strToCopy));
```

Note also that you won't actually see the null character and what comes after it as in your expected output. The output will simply stop at the null terminator because it indicates the end of the string.

Comment: Just a comment on the "add null in case of termination": Sometimes just working with a truncated string may be OK. In other cases, ignoring data may not be acceptable. Good error handling if strings are to long is then unavoidable. Even just exiting rater than truncation would the be preferable.